# Syncing Javascript State across UI

Tags: reactjs, model, synchronization, state, mobx

There are a lot of questions on syncing state between devices or from external storage to/from the UI. This question is about state within the UI.

The UI may have multiple state objects that can point to one entity.
Eg. Multiple User Models that have the same ID and are essentially the same User in the Database.

The second option is to have a pattern that prevents multiple entities and enforces a single Entity is never duplicated.
Eg. Retrieving a User Model with ID=1 will always return the same Model.

So the options I currently face:

1. Have multiple Models point to the same DB entity
2. Enforce a single Instance of a Model reflects a DB entity

Both of these have their tradeoffs:

### Have multiple Models point to the same DB entity

This requires syncing the Models with the same ID when a copy if updated.
This becomes non-trivial in implementation.
The current implementation we have is an EntityManager that keeps copies of each model and will propagate writes to all copies.
It however has complexities in syncing due to async writes to the remote copies, reads from other devices and remote fetches as well as reactions (mobx) within models need to ensure they are reacting to a consistent state of the model.

### Enforce a single Instance of a Model reflects a DB entity

This requires no work to sync. However we have the complexity of ensuring we don't have any copies of a Model pointing to the same DB entity.
This becomes subject to coding conventions.

Eg.

```
model.fromJSON({ title: 'foo' })
model.fetch()
```

Becomes

```
model = model.fromJSON({ title: 'foo' })
model = model.fetch()
```

This is hard to understand for new developers and can be missed over time creating hard to debug   errors.

The question is how do you generally solve this scenario with a consistent and the least complex in terms of bugs case.

Comment: There is an interesting talk about similar thing from Tuomas Artman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxK11RsLqp4&t=2171s But I am afraid there is no such library exists in open source, everyone doing their own. Me too already made 2 similar libraries for my work projects. I think it is missing piece for MobX ecosystem, would be great to have something like that available

Comment: @Danila Hi, would you be able to share the libraries you created or a description of how you went about implementing it?

Comment: Maybe [Repository pattern?](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Basically single point of entry for all models.

Comment: @bucabay I cannot share the code but they are quite similar to the one in the video I posted before, but more tightly coupled to application logic so less reusable for other generic cases.